# Put a php string in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have this string in php

```
$tagged
```

and I want to put it in my javacript script inside the ' '

```
tagName: '',
```

how do I do this

Answer (score 1):

The best way IMHO would be this:

```
tagName: <?php echo json_encode($tagged); ?>
```

This way, you don't have to take care of escaping quotes, escape characters or other unwanted signs.

Comment: why not just `echo json_encode($tagged)` instead?

Comment: I cannot see any benefits over just using json_encode. Please explain the parenthesis as well as the appended "a"

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks, I didn't know `json_encode()` handle raw strings properly. @Downvoters: I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If your view is rendered by PHP:

```
tagName: '<?= json_encode($tagged)?>',
```

If your JS code is a part of a PHP view, build the object from PHP:

```
$jsObject = json_encode(array('tagName' => $tagged'));
```

Comment: why not just `echo json_encode($tagged)` instead?

Comment: My initial response had that, but someone else suggested the same (which is now removed). Updated my initial answer.